# ini file not being ready properly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I keep getting this error:

Warning: mysql_connect(): Unknown MySQL server host 'elephant' (1) 4

My ini file is this:

```
[Database]
DBHostName = "localhost"
DatabaseName = "elephant"
DBUserName = "elephant"
DBPassword = "practice"

[Config]
ConfigTableName = "stage2_config"
Skin="purple"
```

My file that reads the ini file and gives the error is this on the line with the double bold stars. I have no idea what is going on here and why it says the host isn't localhost.

```
<?php
 $gv_SystemTest = "<h2>system.php has been included</h2>";

 $gv_SystemFileInfo = pathinfo(__FILE__); 
 $gv_SystemDirectory = $gv_SystemFileInfo['dirname'] . '/';
 $gv_SystemINIpath = $gv_SystemDirectory . '';

 $gv_SiteGlobals = parse_ini_file($gv_SystemINIpath . $_SERVER['WIA_SYSTEM_INI'], true);


 function echoContent($p_ContentID) {
 global $gv_SiteGlobals;

 $fv_dbLink = mysql_connect($gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DBHostName'],
 $gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DBUserName'],
 $gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DBPassword']);
 **mysql_connect($gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DatabaseName']);**

 $fv_TheQuery = "select *from wia_content where content_id = $p_ContentID";
```

Comment: `error_log(print_r($gv_SiteGlobals,1));` see what returns.

Comment: **mysql_connect($gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DatabaseName']);** why do yo uuse this line

Answer (score 1):

The function `mysql_connect` does not allow to select a database as you tried on this line.

```
mysql_connect($gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DatabaseName']);
```

To connect and select a database, you need to use the function `mysql_select_db` in addition to `mysql_connect`.

```
$link = mysql_connect('host','username','password');
$selected = mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Answer (score 0):

Dont use mysql use only mysqli or pdo

I think you want to select db

to select db you should be mysql_select_db()

```
mysql_select_db('foo', $link);
```

your error in this line

```
mysql_connect($gv_SiteGlobals['Database']['DatabaseName']);
```

it should be of the form

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```